# lexerr error with non-english letters

Tags: angularjs

Being fairly new to Angular js, I'm having this error due to ö character.

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 8-8 [ö] in expression [item.Teközel].
```

I'm using ngSanitize like this at the start of my controller

```
var app = angular.module('xApp', ['smart-table', 'ngSanitize']);
```

but still during page rendering it gives the error above.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ege Bayrak as unicode characters are present in the variable name this `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 8-8 [ö] in expression [ctrl.Teközel].` error occurs

If you have a very few variables in the JavaScript object you could do `item['Teközel']` in the view to perform the data binding but that might be a bad practice or not a recommended approach I think.

If you are having more unicode identifiers or to do it in a more appropriate way you can read this [Lexer support for non-ascii literals #2174](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2174) there might be other approaches to solve the problem in a way that suites your needs (and the set of unicode characters you're using) in that issue #2174 thread than the one I've used below.

To fix this issue we can modify a function in the angular.js file which tells whether the identifier used i.e. the variable name is valid or not

I've modified this function `isValidIdentifierStart` in AngularJS 1.5.8 and the data binding works

```
isValidIdentifierStart: function(ch) {
    return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
            'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
            '_' === ch || ch === '$' ||
            (129 <= ch.charCodeAt(0) && ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 496));
  }
```

You can search for the statement `'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z'` in the version of angular.js file you are using to add the code in order to make the function allow unicode characters

The view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
        <span ng-bind="ctrl.Teközel"></span>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The AngularJS code

```
angular
    .module('demo', [])
    .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

    function DefaultController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.Teközel = 'Hello, World!';
    }
```

To check whether the identifier name is valid or not we can use this [validator](https://mothereff.in/js-variables)

Comment: I changed the function inside minified script and it works so far so good.